# Crystal Reports 2013 monthly incremental average

Tags: graph, crystal-reports, average

Good morning,

I'm trying to get a graph on Crystal Reports 2013 showing the monthly average number of tickets closed from 01/01/2016 till now but I am only able to graph the total count of tickets month by month and his running count.

Since my technical english could be misunderstood I'll give an example.
Let's suppose that my DB query gives me only ticket ID and closing date, and I have:

50 tickets closed on january  (the average per month is 50)

120 tickets closed on february (the average per month is 120+50/2=85)

100 tickets closed on march (the average per month is 120+50+100/3=90)
etc.

In my graph I am able to graph the values 50-120-100 and the running count 50-170-270 but I am not able to graph 50-85-90

Thank you very much.